# Merge two documents linewise

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

Im trying to merge two documents doc_a and doc_b into a third documents say doc_c with the desired result being:

```
content doc_a: line1 
               line2

content doc_b: line3 
               line4

content doc_c: line1 line3  
               line2 line4
```

My approach is similar to this:

```
public static void mergeTrain(File src1, File src2, File dest) throws IOException{      

    Files.copy(src1.toPath(), dest.toPath());

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(src2));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dest,true));

    String line = new String("Platzhalter");
    try {
        while(line != null){
            line = br.readLine();
            if (line !=null){               
                bw.append(line);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    br.close();
    bw.close();
}
```

As a result I optain instead:

```
content doc_c: line1  
               line2 line3 line4
```

How can I optain my desired result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently copying the contents of `src1` into the destination file `dest`, then you append all lines from file `src2` - and that's exactly what you get. How about you do what you actually explained you wanted to?

How about this:

```
public static void mergeTrain(File src1, File src2, File dest) throws IOException {      

    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(src1));
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(src2));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dest,true));

    String line1;
    String line2;

    try {
        while((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null
           && (line2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {            
            bw.append(line1 + " " + line2);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    br1.close();
    br2.close();
    bw.close();
}
```

I didn't test the code, but you should get the idea at least.
Note that you will need to think about what you want to do if both files have different number of lines.

Comment: Note: I don't think the `NumberFormatException` actually belongs there. I just copied that from your original code.

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you parse the two input files together. Note also the two files may have different lenght.

```
public static void mergeTrain(File src1, File src2, File dest) throws IOException{      
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(src1));
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(src2));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dest,true));

String line1 = "";
String line2 = "";
try {
    while(line1 != null || line2!=null){
        line1 = line1 !=null && br1.readLine();
        line2 = line2 != null && br2.readLine();
        if (line1 !=null) && (line2!=null){               
            bw.append(line1).append(" ").append(line2).append("\n");
            }
        } else if (line1!=null) {
            bw.append(line1).append("\n");           
        } else if (line2!=null) {
            bw.append(line2).append("\n");             
        }
    }
    br1.close();
    br2.close();
    bw.close();


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```